# SSIS Data Flow Task Source as Tabbed Delimited File not reading last line throws partial data on last line error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Following is sample from my application

Source- Tabbed Delimited file Col1 Col2 Col2 aa a 1 2 da a 1 2 ca a 1 2 ba a 1 2

Destination- OLE DB Table

create table test_data_1 (col1 varchar(100), col2 int, col3 varchar(100))

Issue- all the rows are copied Except the last Row, when check debug file, there is a warning saying last line has Partial data hence ignored.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue in SSIS?

Data is valid data.

Comment: Please post format of the file properly .Did u mean like this :- Col1 Col2 Col3 aa a 1 2 da a

Comment: Do you have a blank line at the end of a file?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, really annoying!

I found that when I opened the connection manager the following was in `Text qualifier:` on the `General` tab: `_x003C_none_x003E_`. This should be set to `&lt;none&gt;`. Just delete the value that is there, click OK, and when you run it should load all rows in.

It appears that this may be something to do with SVN, and may reoccur.